# Sort file names in a single directory by directory depth

Tags: arrays, ruby

After using `Dir.glob` to find all file with the same name in a directory and its sub-directories, is there a way to sort this array of results by subdirectory depth so that the the current directory is at the top and the lowest subdirectory is the last element in the array?

Answer (score 2):

`Dir.glob` returns the filenames as an array of strings, and the strings can be sorted by the count of `/`  in them, as follows:

```
Dir.glob(....).sort{|a, b| a.count('/') <=> b.count('/')}
```

For a reverse sort order:

```
Dir.glob(....).sort{|a, b| b.count('/') <=> a.count('/')}
```

Comment: Easier and faster: `.sort_by { |x| x.count('/') }` (reverse: `.sort_by { |x| -x.count('/') }`) - sort_by invokes the Ruby block N times then does O(N log N) comparisons on the results in C code; sort invokes the Ruby block O(N log N) times.